# How to redirect STDERR to both file and console and STDOUT to file only

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

What I want to achieve is redirect both normal message and error message to a file. But also print the error message to the console (only error message).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One (out of many) solutions is the following:

```
command 2>&1 1>logfile | tee -a logfile
```

Key:

```
`2>&1` redirect the output of STDERR to STDOUT
`1>logfile` redirect STDOUT (note: leaves STDERR unchanged)
`| tee -a logfile` append the redirected STDERR to the logfile
```

For more information, see the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial)

Comment: Before I think after redirect `2>&1`, the `1` holds everything, no matter where your redirect the `1` later, STDERR goes together.

Comment: @EnzoChi The redirect `2>&1` tells bash to redirect STDERR to the same fd (file descriptor) as where STDOUT `currently` goes. It is not redirecting it to STDOUT. If you then redirect STDOUT (`1>logfile`), STDERR won't be affected, it will still be pointing to the same fd. The order of doing the redirections is important.

Comment: can be slightly shortened: `command 2> >(tee -a logfile) 1>>logfile` -- stderr is redirected into a process substitution, and tee writes to stdout. No real benefit over your answer.

Comment: So, 1 and 2 are just pointers, taking a program's stdout & stderr messages and normally putting them to terminal/screen, unless changed/redirected/piped. Making `2>&1` doesn't "attach" 2 to 1, but just attaches 2 to whatever 1 *was* pointing to, at that time...?

Comment: @Xen2050 That is correct :-) For  more information see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/redirection_tutorial

Comment: nice solution, except if you need the exit value of `command`.